# Deploying Rails apps - Benefits of using Passenger, Capistrano & Co?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

On http://rubyonrails.org/deploy/ it is recommended to use Passenger, Capistrano for deployment.

Since Passenger costs 30$/month I would be interested in what are the benefits of it compared to other options.

Can't I just buy some webspace(for about 2,3$/month) , upload my rails project and start the server in production mode?

Because if I just make a webpage with a bit of dynamic content & use RuR for it 30$/month would be a hard pill to swallow.

What other deployment options can you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I have used [mina](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina) for my project. It's fast deployment tools currently. You will not wait long time to wait your deployment process combine with git. You can use [mina-multistage](https://github.com/endoze/mina-multistage) when you have many domains based on you branch.
I my project I use:

- GIT for versioning code
- Mina for development tools
- Nginx for server

I hope this can help you to make decision.